Integrate unit normal vector over unit sphere intersected with a simplicial cone
Let $S^{d-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^d$. Consider a ($d$-dimensional) simplicial cone $C$ in $\mathbb R^d$ whose extremal rays are spanned by some unit vectors $\mathbf{u}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_d$. Let $\Sigma=C\cap S^{d-1}$. I would like to compute the integral $\mathbf{I}=\int_\Sigma\mathbf{N}\,d\Sigma$, where $\mathbf N$ is the unit normal vector at each point on the sphere and $d\Sigma$ is the $(d-1)$-dimensional volume element on the sphere. For example, if $d=3$, then $\Sigma$ is a region on the $2$-dimensional unit sphere $S^2$, and $\mathbf{I}$ is the "area vector" of $\Sigma$. I'd like to express $\mathbf{I}$ in terms of $\mathbf{u_1},\ldots,\mathbf{u_d}$.
The simplest case is when $d=2$. In this case, $\Sigma$ is an arc on the unit circle whose endpoints are $\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$. I can easily compute that $$\mathbf{I}=||\mathbf{u}_2-\mathbf{u}_1||\frac{\mathbf{u}_1+\mathbf{u}_2}{||\mathbf{u}_1+\mathbf{u}_2||}.$$
Now suppose $d=3$. Using Stokes' theorem, I can write the integral $\mathbf{I}$ as $$\frac{1}{2}\oint_{\partial\Sigma}\mathbf{r}\times d\mathbf{r},$$ where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector of a point on the boundary of $\Sigma$. I can rewrite this integral as
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3\oint_{A_i}\mathbf{r}\times d\mathbf{r},$$ where $A_i$ is the geodesic arc on the sphere going from $\mathbf{u}_i$ to $\mathbf{u}_{i+1}$ (where $\mathbf{u}_4=\mathbf{u}_1$). Note that the angle $\theta_i$ between $\mathbf{u}_i$ and $\mathbf{u}_{i+1}$ is easy to compute since $\cos\theta_i=\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\mathbf{u}_{i+1}$. Let $$\mathbf{n}_i=\frac{\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{u}_{i+1}}{||\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{u}_{i+1}||}$$ be a unit normal vector to the plane containing $A_i$. Let $$\mathbf{v}_i=\frac{\mathbf{n}_i\times\mathbf{u}_i}{||\mathbf{n}_i\times\mathbf{u}_i||}.$$ Then we can parametrize the arc $A_i$ by
$$\mathbf{r}(\phi)=\mathbf{u}_i\cos\phi+\mathbf{v}_i\sin\phi.$$
Along the arc $A_i$, we have \begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}\times d\mathbf{r}&=\mathbf{r(\phi)}\times \frac{d\mathbf{r}(\phi)}{d\phi}d\phi \\ 
&=(\mathbf{u}_i\cos\phi+\mathbf{v}_i\sin\phi)\times(-\mathbf{u}_i\sin\phi+\mathbf{v}_i\cos\phi)d\phi \\ 
&=(-\cos\phi\sin\phi\,\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{u}_i+\cos^2\phi\,\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{v}_i+\sin^2\phi\,\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{v}_i+\sin\phi\cos\phi\,\mathbf{v}_i\times\mathbf{v}_i)d\phi \\ 
&=(\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{v}_i)d\phi \\ &=\mathbf{n}_i\,d\phi. 
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}\mathbf{I}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3\int_0^{\theta_i}\mathbf{n_i}d\phi \\ 
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3\theta_i\mathbf{n_i} \\ 
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3\theta_i\frac{\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{u}_{i+1}}{||\mathbf{u}_i\times\mathbf{u}_{i+1}||}. 
\end{align*}
Is there a similar approach that works in higher dimensions? Has this been worked out somewhere already (i.e., is there a reference)?

Given a set of linearly independent vectors $S = \{s_0, \ldots, s_k\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, define
$$
\Delta(S) = \{c_1 s_1 + \cdots + c_k s_k \mid c_i \geq 0\} \cap \mathbb{S}^{n}, \; \Delta^\circ(S) = \{c_1 s_1 + \cdots + c_k s_k \mid c_i > 0 \} \cap \mathbb{S}^{n}
$$
to be the closed and open spherical polytopes defined by $S$, which is a $k$-dimensional submanifold with corners whenever $k \leq n$. Furthermore, the locus of points with index $\leq 1$ (in the sense described here), denoted by $\Delta^{\leq 1}(S)$, is a submanifold with boundary $\partial \Delta^{\leq 1}(S) = \Delta^{\circ}(S_0) \sqcup \cdots \sqcup \Delta^{\circ}(S_k)$, where $S_i = S - \{s_i\}$.
We fix $k = n$ and, for brevity, write $\Delta = \Delta_S$ and $\Delta^\circ_i = \Delta^\circ(S_i)$. The problem amounts to computing
$$
\int_{\Delta} \mathbf{r}\omega,
$$
where $\mathbf{r} = x^i\mathbf{e}_i$ is the radial vector field and $\omega$ is the volume form on $\mathbb{S}^{n}$. To do this, first define a bilinear map $\times \colon \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \times \Lambda^{n-1} \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $v \times w = \star (v \wedge w)$, where $\star$ is the Hodge star; this is a generalization of the cross product. Then
$$
\langle \mathbf{e}_i, \mathbf{e}_j \times (\mathbf{e}_{k_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathbf{e}_{k_{n-1}}) \rangle = \langle \mathbf{e}_i, \star (\mathbf{e}_j \wedge \mathbf{e}_{k_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathbf{e}_{k_{n-1}}) \rangle = (-1)^{n} \epsilon_{ijk_1\cdots k_{n-1}},
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. Consider the $\Lambda^{n-1} \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$-valued differential form $\mathrm{d}^{n-1}\mathbf{r} \in \Omega^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, \Lambda^{n-1}\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ given by
$$
\mathrm{d}^{n-1}\mathbf{r} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \sum_{|K| = n-1} \mathbf{e}_K \, \mathrm{d}x^{K},
$$
where $K$ ranges over all $(n-1)$-tuples $(k_1, \ldots, k_{n-1})$ of elements in $[n] = \{0, \ldots, n\}$. It follows that
$$
\mathbf{r} \times \mathrm{d}^{n-1}\mathbf{r} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \cdot (-1)^n \epsilon_{ijk_1\cdots k_{n-1}}  x^j \,\mathbf{e}_i \, \mathrm{d}x^{k_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{k_{n-1}}.
$$
We now move onto the sphere, on which the pullbacks of $\mathrm{d}x^i$ fail to be linearly independent. They are related by the equation $x^i \mathrm{d}x^i = 0$, which implies that
$$
(-1)^j x^i \, \mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{\mathrm{d}x^j} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^n = (-1)^{i} x^j\,\mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{\mathrm{d}x^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^n
$$
for all $i, j \in [n]$. The volume form $\omega$ on the sphere is given by the interior product with the radial vector field, which means
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{r} \omega = \mathbf{r}\iota_{\mathbf{r}} (\mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^n) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{j-1} x^i x^j \mathbf{e}_i \, \mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{\mathrm{d}x^j} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^n \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} (x^j)^2 \mathbf{e}_i \, \mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{\mathrm{d}x^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^n \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} \mathbf{e}_i \, \mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \cdots \wedge \widehat{\mathrm{d}x^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^n \\
&= \frac{1}{n!}
 \epsilon_{ij_1\cdots j_{n}} \mathbf{e}_i \, \mathrm{d}x^{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{j_{n}}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $\mathrm{d}(\mathbf{r} \times \mathrm{d}^{n-1}\mathbf{r}) = (-1)^n n \cdot \mathbf{r}\omega$, so by Stokes' theorem, we have
$$
\int_{\Delta} \mathbf{r} \omega = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \int_{\Delta_i^{\circ}} (-1)^n \cdot  \mathbf{r} \times \mathrm{d}^{n-1}\mathbf{r}.
$$
Induce on $\mathscr{S}_i = \operatorname{span} S_i$ the orientation of $\Delta^\circ_i$, and let $\nu_i$ be the unit normal vector
to $\mathscr{S}_i$. If $\operatorname{vol}$ is the volume form in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then we may write $\omega = \iota_{\mathbf{r}} \operatorname{vol}$, which in turn induces volume forms $\theta_i$ on $\Delta^\circ_i$ by $\theta_i = \iota_{\nu_i} \omega$. Note that $\mathrm{d}^{k}\mathbf{r}_x(w) = w$ for any wedge $w \in \Lambda^{k}(\mathrm{T}_x \mathbb{R}^{n+1})$. It follows that for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $w \in \Lambda^{n-1}(\mathrm{T}_x \Delta^\circ_i)$,
$$
\langle v, (\mathbf{r} \times \mathrm{d}^{n-1}\mathbf{r})_x(w) \rangle = \langle{v, \star(x \wedge w) \rangle} = (-1)^{n} \operatorname{vol} (v \wedge x \wedge w),
$$
which vanishes for $v \in \mathscr{S}_i$. For $\nu_i$, we have $\langle \nu_i , \mathbf{r} \times \mathrm{d}^{n-1}\mathbf{r} \rangle = (-1)^n \iota_{\nu_i} \iota_{\mathbf{r}} \operatorname{vol} = (-1)^n \theta_i$. It follows that
$$
\int_{\Delta} \mathbf{r}\omega = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \int_{\Delta^\circ_i} \nu_i\theta_i = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \nu_i \operatorname{vol}_{\mathscr{S}_i}(\Delta_i).
$$
The volume of the spherical $(n-1)$-simplices $\Delta_i \subseteq \mathscr{S}_i$ can be described as a function of the dihedral angles $\angle (\mathscr{S}_i \cap \mathscr{S}_j, \mathscr{S}_i \cap \mathscr{S}_k)$ by the Schläfli formula. For even-dimensional spheres, there is a recursive formula given by Schläfli in terms of lower-dimensional simplices possessing a subset of the dihedral angles of $\Delta_i$. Other formulae may be found in the work of Aomoto, Coxeter, and Satô.
References
Schläfli, Ludwig, Collected mathematical works. Vol. II, Basel: Birkhäuser Verlag. 381 p. (1953). ZBL0051.24102.
Aomoto, Kazuhiko, Analytic structure of Schläfli function, Nagoya Math. J. 68, 1-16 (1977). ZBL0382.33010.
Coxeter, H. S. M., The functions of Schläfli and Lobatschefsky., Quart. Journ. of Math. 6, 13-29 (1935). ZBL61.0395.02.
Satô, Kenzi, Spherical simplices and their polars, Q. J. Math. 58, No. 1, 107-126 (2007). ZBL1153.51009.

+1 Great answer.
